# MongoDB percent complete estimation?

Tags: mongodb

Anyone know a way to estimate the percent complete a query is in MongoDB?  If I'm running a long query, it'd be nice to say, OK, it's 40% done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Option 1: Split long operation into small operations.*

Almost always you can split long operation into smaller operations. Lets say if you need update 1.000.000 of documents you can run update operation that will update all documents at once or you can update 50.000 at once.(after each 50.000 + 5% was done)

*Option 2: Make fake progress.*

Approximately estimate operation duration and make *fake* progress bar.

In general I don't believe that there is a database that support callbacks that's will notify you about performed percent of an operation. Mongodb does not support it as well, as @user196251 said.